# window.location.hostname without www added

Tags: javascript

How can I make the code below return the result without www. in front of the hostname?

```
javascript:var stats=window.open('http:/'+'/www.hosterstats.com/historicaldns.php?domain='+window.location.hostname.replace('#','|'));
```

Comment: Is there an error when you take out `www` from the string?

Comment: I suppose you could call `.replace()` on the string, like you already do.

Comment: add `.replace(/^www\./, '')`

Comment: The `www` isn't "added," it's a very important part of the origin. Some sites use it, some don't, but when a subdomain is present it becomes critical to the origin.

Comment: Thanks for the input. When the script pulls domain= I need that part to be stripped of the www. - it's the only way the site i'm trying to view will load correctly.

Comment: Thanks adassko, that didn't work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
javascript: var stats = window.open('http:/'+'/www.hosterstats.com/historicaldns.php?domain='+window.location.hostname.replace('#','|').replace('www.',''));
```